Firebase snapshot doesn't exist
Log.d("ıd check",subCatId+catId);
database.getReference().child("categories").child(catId)
.child("subCategories").child(subCatId)
.child("questions").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d("exixtance","DOES EXİSTS");
            timer.start();
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                prossesdata(dataSnapshot);
                loadingdialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    binding.optioncontainer.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            checkAnswer((Button) v);
                        }
                    });
                }
                playAnimation(binding.question, 0, list.get(position).getQuestion());

                binding.buttonnext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        enableOptions(true);
                        position++;
                        if (position == list.size()) {
                            timer.cancel();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);
                            long totaltime = questionTime * 60 * 100;
                            intent.putExtra("timetaken", totaltime - timeLeft);
                            intent.putExtra("correct", correctAnswer);
                            intent.putExtra("wrong", wrongAnswer);
                            intent.putExtra("totalquestion", list.size());
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                            return;
                        }
                        count = 0;
                        playAnimation(binding.question, 0, list.get(position).getQuestion());
                    }
                });

                binding.buttonsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this, ScoreActivity.class);
                        long totaltime = questionTime * 60 * 100;
                        intent.putExtra("timetaken", totaltime - timeLeft);
                        intent.putExtra("correct", correctAnswer);
                        intent.putExtra("wrong", wrongAnswer);
                        intent.putExtra("totalquestion", list.size());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(QuestionActivity.this, ""+list.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingdialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

I am trying to get the questions from database, but my code just performs the else part and skips the first part. I can't understand why.
How can I fix this problem and make the first part work? The snapshot doesn't exist, thus I can't fill the if condition.
I added the log and this is the ouput:

2024-10-06 17:39:26.060 23619-23619 ıd check                com.example.quiztime D  -O8IX4259O4p5Ko_uh4e-O8GtSPIwhXwbPfYy0Bc

And this is my realtime database :
{
  "categories": {
    "-O8GtSPIwhXwbPfYy0Bc": {
      "categoryImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/quiztimeadminapp.appspot.com/o/categoryImage%2F1727950867993?alt=media&token=312244da-1e8e-4188-8f81-b7b81d056125",
      "categoryName": "almanca ",
      "subCategories": {
        "-O8HS_G7EjfqXDUij4El": {
          "categoryName": "a1 almanca",
          "questions": {
            "-O8LtLHmg-9rgchOJiKT": {
              "correctAnswer": "Bukres ",
              "optionA": "Londra ",
              "optionB": "Bukres ",
              "optionC": "Paris ",
              "optionD": "Madrid",
              "question": "ingilterenin baskenti neresidir "
            },
            "-O8WplOEJ9gMN_tW0DjM": {
              "correctAnswer": "Sjsj",
              "optionA": "Sjsj",
              "optionB": "Sjsj",
              "optionC": "Sjjs",
              "optionD": "Sjdj",
              "question": "deneme 2"
            }
          }
        },
        "-O8IX4259O4p5Ko_uh4e": {
          "categoryName": "a2 almanca"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


If snapshot.exists() returns false, it seems that no node exists at /categories/$catId/subCategories/$subCatId in your database. If that is unexpected, edit your question to show us why. For example: log the value of catId and subCatId right before you use them and show us that updated code and its output, then show us the relevant JSON from your database (as text, no screenshots please) that show there actually is data at that path with those IDs.

Please edit your question (there's a small link right under it for this purpose) to show: 1) the updated code that logs the values right before you use them, 2) the output of those log statements, 3) the relevant JSON from the database (as text, no screenshots please) that show there actually is data at that path with those IDs.

sorry for that but actually ı am new to firebase and android how can get the json from database as text do u want me to copy all of the structure

https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6386780?hl=en#export&zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Note that the -O8IX4259O4p5Ko_uh4e key you logged appears nowhere in the data you shared, so we have no way to match the code of to the data. In order to understand what is going on, we need to be able to map the code to the data.

as you mentioned before ı exported the json file and view it as text but when ı copy the json in here it loses its code structure ı dont know how to send you the json data and ı have that ıds in my database ı edited the main question with the data that contains logged values

You can put triple backticks around the JSON, but if you can't get that to work - somebody will fix it for you.

@AlexMamo ı edited the question with json like Frank van pullen said with backticks

Did you try to use hardcoded values for catId and subCatId. Do you get the same behavior?

Do you mean putting the actual id values instead of the subcatıd and catıd string

@FrankvanPuffelen ı tried to put the logged ıd values directly into code and ı still get the same error

Your code reads data from this path:
/categories/$catId/subCategories/$subCatId/questions

If we look at the JSON you shared, this is the closest path to that:
{
  "categories": {
    "-O8GtSPIwhXwbPfYy0Bc": {
      "categoryImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/quiztimeadminapp.appspot.com/o/categoryImage%2F1727950867993?alt=media&token=312244da-1e8e-4188-8f81-b7b81d056125",
      "categoryName": "almanca ",
      "subCategories": {
        "-O8IX4259O4p5Ko_uh4e": {
          "categoryName": "a2 almanca"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

But there is no questions node under the -O8IX4259O4p5Ko_uh4e subcategory (only a categoryName). So it is indeed expected that snapshot.exists() returns false in the code you shared, as it reads a node that doesn't exist in your database.
If you want to make the code work, add a questions node under subcategory -O8IX4259O4p5Ko_uh4e, similar to the one you have under subcategory -O8HS_G7EjfqXDUij4El.

Log.d("ID Check", "catId: " + catId + " subCatId: " + subCatId);

database.getReference()
.child("categories")
.child(catId)
.child("subCategories")
.child(subCatId)
.child("questions")
.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            // Process the data
            Log.d("Existence", "Data exists in the path.");
        } else {
            Log.d("Existence", "Snapshot does not exist");
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        Log.e("FirebaseError", error.getMessage());
    }
});

Check rules
{
  "rules": {
    "categories": {
      "$catId": {
        "subCategories": {
          "$subCatId": {
            "questions": {
              ".read": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Debugging logs
Log.d("ID Check", "Category ID: " + catId + ", Subcategory ID: " + subCatId);

